# click next button inside table when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I have a table with input and button next to it.

the respective button should be clicked when enter is pressed on the input.

```
$('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
     $(this).find('.btn').click(function() {
       alert( "clicked" );
      });
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elyor/b809Lxra/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is on <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress you are actually adding a `click` event lister but not actually triggering a button click. You can fix it by putting the `click` event listener outside and on enter simply trigger that event.

Also,

```
$(this).find('.btn')
```

logic is not correct as `.inputs` is inside on `td` and `.btn` is inside another `td`, so doing `$(this).find('.btn')` gives you nothing at all as there is no `.btn` element inside `.inputs` element.

You can use this instead:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.btn')
```

This will find the [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) table row `tr` for the current `.inputs` element and then find the `.btn` element inside that row using `.find('.btn')`.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.inputs').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn').click()
  }
});

$('.half').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="half">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="inputs" name="ragsoc" type="text" class="text-sx" id="ragsoc" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="tdocra c_white b"><a href="" class="btn">BUTTON</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="inputs" name="ragsoc" type="text" class="text-sx" id="ragsoc" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="tdocra c_white b"><a href="" class="btn">BUTTON</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="inputs" name="ragsoc" type="text" class="text-sx" id="ragsoc" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="tdocra c_white b"><a href="" class="btn">BUTTON</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you use a single function that is called if enter is pressed OR button is clicked?

```
function doSomething(){
  alert('clicked');
}

$('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
     doSomething();
});

$(".btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  doSomething();
}
```